# Libgdx - min and max of a rotated Bounding Box

Tags: libgdx, bounding-box

I am running the simple code below:

```
BoundingBox bounds = new BoundingBox();
Vector3 vmin = new Vector3();
Vector3 vmax = new Vector3();

vmin.x = -1;
vmin.y = -2;
vmin.z = 0;  
vmax.x = 1;
vmax.y = 2;
vmax.z = 0;
bounds.set(vmin,vmax);

Matrix4 mrot = new Matrix4();
mrot.setToRotation(0, 0, 1, 90);
bounds.mul(mrot);

Gdx.app.log("xxx","minx " + bounds.min.x);
Gdx.app.log("xxx","maxx " + bounds.max.x);
Gdx.app.log("xxx","miny " + bounds.min.y);
Gdx.app.log("xxx","maxy " + bounds.max.y);
Gdx.app.log("xxx","dimx " + bounds.getWidth());
Gdx.app.log("xxx","dimy " + bounds.getHeight());
```

Log shows:

minx -2.0   // ok, as expected 
 
maxx 2.0    // ok, as expected 
miny -2.0   // I would expect -1 ! 
maxy 2.0    // I would expect 1 ! 
dimx 4.0    // ok, as expected 
dimy 4.0    // I would expect 2 !

My understanding would that the code above should simply rotate a 2D rectangle of 90° around the Z-axis. Results from the Log show that it is not the case (i.e. no change to the y coordinates)

Does anyone can help me understand where I am mistaken?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some code dissecting I believe it's a libGDX bug. That's the `mul` function of `BoundingBox`

```
public BoundingBox mul (Matrix4 transform) {
        final float x0 = min.x, y0 = min.y, z0 = min.z, x1 = max.x, y1 = max.y, z1 = max.z;
        ext(tmpVector.set(x0, y0, z0).mul(transform));
        ext(tmpVector.set(x0, y0, z1).mul(transform));
        ext(tmpVector.set(x0, y1, z0).mul(transform));
        ext(tmpVector.set(x0, y1, z1).mul(transform));
        ext(tmpVector.set(x1, y0, z0).mul(transform));
        ext(tmpVector.set(x1, y0, z1).mul(transform));
        ext(tmpVector.set(x1, y1, z0).mul(transform));
        ext(tmpVector.set(x1, y1, z1).mul(transform));
        return this;
    }
```

And `ext`:

```
public BoundingBox ext (Vector3 point) {
        return this.set(min.set(min(min.x, point.x), min(min.y, point.y), min(min.z, point.z)),
            max.set(Math.max(max.x, point.x), Math.max(max.y, point.y), Math.max(max.z, point.z)));
    }
```

If you look closely, the `ext` function does some `min` and `max` with the current points. That is what causes your error. That function should reset the min and max points (to POSITIVE_INFINITY and NEGATIVE_INFINITY respectively) before any operation.

EDIT:

It seems it was already fixed on the [git repository](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/0a52109edcd7036062f1aa0dc525837e3c49ec76). You can use the latest nightly or wait for the next release.

Comment: Many Thanks for your anwser. I am using the Gradle setup app which does not seem to have fixed this issue yet