# Calculating a 2D rectangle around 3D object

Tags: 3d, libgdx

I have a 3D object that is moving and rotating.
What I want to achieve, is to show on the screen the surrounding 2D box of my 3D object. (I would define its 2D box as the smallest rectangle that contains my 3D object when projected on the screen.)
Here is a quick drawing to show what I mean: http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/719280exemple.png

I have tried using a 3D bounding box but the resulting 2D projection is too large (projected corners of the rotated 3D box can be quite far away from the actual vertices). A 2D bounding box following the 3D object rotations does not work either (as it is flat, a e.g. 90° rotation around the x axis would project my 2D box as a line) 
One alternative approach could be to look at all vertices of my 3D object and to determine which ones are the min/max in x/y. Yet : (i) this might be cpu consuming especially for big models and (ii) I cannot find a way to access the (transformed) vertices of my 3D Object anyway - I am using libgdx.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Many thanks

PS: I have also posted this on the libgdx forum but I guess this is not only libgdx-related

Comment: have you tried to `project` the 3d bounding box with the camera you are rendering?

Comment: Thanks. This would work indeed. Yet my struggle was related to a libgdx bug (cf. my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the reason I was struggling is because of a bug in the current stable version of Libgdx that made the calculation of rotated boundingbox wrong. (see: [Libgdx - min and max of a rotated Bounding Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775364/libgdx-min-and-max-of-a-rotated-bounding-box) and https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/0a52109edcd7036062f1aa0dc525837e3c49ec76)

This has been corrected in the last nightlies.

It works now, and one can get the 2D bounding box either via Camera.project as indicated by cfrick or simply by getting BoundingBox.min/max in case of an orthographic projection (my case)